# Firefox cache2 'doomed' folder

Tags: firefox, files, cache

I was recently looking in my Firefox cache as I have made it so that it does not cache:

[image: Cached Web Content Firefox Settings]

And I found this folder called `doomed`:

```
/home/arthur-dent/.cache/mozilla/firefox/k29gs42c.default/cache2/doomed
```

So I am wondering what this folder is and what its purpose is? And does it signify that I am doomed?

Here are some examples of some of the files contained within it:

```
-rw------- 1 arthur-dent arthur-dent  2393 May 31 18:49 991673276
-rw------- 1 arthur-dent arthur-dent  2444 May 31 16:46 993458609
-rw------- 1 arthur-dent arthur-dent  3043 May 31 16:47 997747681
```

And viewing them in `nano` says that they are all converted DOS format.

**Information Update:**

Here is an example of the contents of one of the files:

```
0s^Eý^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^AUkHhUkHi;5>Ö^@^@^@^@^@^@^@::https://duckduckgo.com/i.js?q=fat%20pug%20swimming&o=json^@security-info^@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^@request-method^@GET^@response-head^@HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 31 May 2015 17:44:09 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-javascript; charset=UTF-8
Expires: Sun, 31 May 2015 17:44:08 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
x-duckduckgo-locale: en_GB
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Firefox-Spdy: 3.1
^@^@^@^@^@
```

Also the 3 files I listed above have magically disappeared now although many others remain.

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

**Package Information:**

```
firefox:
  Installed: 38.0+build3-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Candidate: 38.0+build3-0ubuntu0.15.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 38.0+build3-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     37.0+build2-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To completely turn off caching in Firefox, open a new tab and type `about:config`, then search for `browser.cache.disk.enable` and double-click it to set it to `false`.

Then delete the cache manually, restart Firefox, and your doomed files will be gone.

The current files are there because your cache is not 0 and that's why they are there, disappear and then get replaced by others...  ;-)

Comment: You might be interested in `browser.cache.disk.enable = false` which makes `cache2` dir of zero size.

Comment: @MttJocy could you delete that comment and then ping me in chat as I've updated the answer with another comment