# How to disable cache in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, security, configuration, settings, cache

From [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630636/firefox-cache2-doomed-folder/630641#630641) I learned previously how to disable the Firefox cache completely, however I have found that in the latest version (don't know when this change was made, but I think rather recently) the `network.http.use-cache` section is not in `about:config` so how can I now properly disable the cache? Has it simply changed its name or is this no longer possible or...? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 and Firefox 46.0.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This option was actually removed in Firefox 43 because it caused [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1198387).

But there are still the following options available through the `about:config` section:

- `browser.cache.disk.enable` (The disk cache is used in normal mode (non Private Browsing mode) and stores persistent data on the hard drive.)
- `browser.cache.memory.enable` (The memory cache is used in normal mode and in Private Browsing mode and is purged when you close Firefox.)

The first should be what you want. It is inadvisable to also disable the second one though as Firefox needs some sort of cache to function properly. Information taken from [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1124186).